# CoercionType doesn't support Image for Excel web add-in

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, onenote-api

For office js API, based on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.coerciontype), Office.CoercionType.Image should be supported in Excel. But I find Office.CoercionType.Image is undefined in Excel Online.  Only Text, Matrix, and Table have values.

[image]

BTW, it seems that OneNote also supports Office.CoercionType.Image which is not listed in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your post, This is a known gap for Office.CoercionType.Image that is not supported for Excel Online at this moment, we have documented for this at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/image-coercion-requirement-sets

What's your scenario? can you use shape.AddImage?

Another suggestion: would you please provide us feedback via https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=163563 and upvote for this feature. thanks for your support.